# Exception running javafx file in JavaSE

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I am trying to run a javafx file in java SE using netbeans, I have imported javafx to the java SE.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.net.ProxySelector;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class WebMap extends Application {
    private Timeline locationUpdateTimeline;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create web engine and view
        final WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine(getClass().getResource("googlemap.html").toString());
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        // create map type buttons
        final ToggleGroup mapTypeGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        final ToggleButton road = new ToggleButton("Road");
        road.setSelected(true);
        road.setToggleGroup(mapTypeGroup);
        final ToggleButton satellite = new ToggleButton("Satellite");
        satellite.setToggleGroup(mapTypeGroup);
        final ToggleButton hybrid = new ToggleButton("Hybrid");
        hybrid.setToggleGroup(mapTypeGroup);
        final ToggleButton terrain = new ToggleButton("Terrain");
        terrain.setToggleGroup(mapTypeGroup);
        mapTypeGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observableValue, Toggle toggle, Toggle toggle1) {
                if (road.isSelected()) {
                    webEngine.executeScript("document.setMapTypeRoad()");
                } else if (satellite.isSelected()) {
                    webEngine.executeScript("document.setMapTypeSatellite()");
                } else if (hybrid.isSelected()) {
                    webEngine.executeScript("document.setMapTypeHybrid()");
                } else if (terrain.isSelected()) {
                    webEngine.executeScript("document.setMapTypeTerrain()");
                }
            }
        });
        // add map source toggles
        ToggleGroup mapSourceGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        final ToggleButton google = new ToggleButton("Google");
        google.setSelected(true);
        google.setToggleGroup(mapSourceGroup);
        final ToggleButton yahoo = new ToggleButton("Yahoo");
        yahoo.setToggleGroup(mapSourceGroup);
        final ToggleButton bing = new ToggleButton("Bing");
        bing.setToggleGroup(mapSourceGroup);
        // listen to selected source
        mapSourceGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observableValue, Toggle toggle, Toggle toggle1) {
                terrain.setDisable(true);
                if (google.isSelected()) {
                    terrain.setDisable(false);
                    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("googlemap.html").toString());
                } else if (yahoo.isSelected()) {
                    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("bingmap.html").toString());
                } else if (bing.isSelected()) {
                    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("yahoomap.html").toString());
                }
                mapTypeGroup.selectToggle(road);
            }
        });

        webEngine.executeScript("document.goToLocation(\""+searchBox.getText()+"\")");
        Button zoomIn = new Button("Zoom In");
        zoomIn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) { webEngine.executeScript("document.zoomIn()"); }
        });
        Button zoomOut = new Button("Zoom Out");
        zoomOut.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) { webEngine.executeScript("document.zoomOut()"); }
        });
        // create toolbar
        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
        toolBar.getStyleClass().add("map-toolbar");
        toolBar.getItems().addAll(
                road, satellite, hybrid, terrain,
                createSpacer(),
                google, yahoo, bing,
                createSpacer(),
                new Label("Location:"), searchBox, zoomIn, zoomOut);
        // create root
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.getStyleClass().add("map");
        root.setCenter(webView);
        root.setTop(toolBar);
        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("Web Map");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1000,700, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("C:/Users/Fatmah/Documents/NetBeansProjects/webmap/WebMap.css");
        // show stage
        stage.show();
    }

    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;        }

    static { // use system proxy settings when standalone application    
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      WebMap.launch(args);
    }

}
```

And this is the exception I'm getting:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(Ljavafx/scene/web/WebEngine;)V
    at webmap.WebMap.start(WebMap.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: @peeskillet Exception in Application start method

Comment: Whats the exception and what line? That information is important

Comment: @peeskillet see edited question for the exception, thanks

Comment: @peeskillet line 38, is a comment. It is where just after the start method. And i dont understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

you need the jdk 1.7 for javafx